# Order SQL Query by multiple cases, in ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with this stored procedure in a local database, in SQL. This procedure as is informs a list of all employees, ordered by their id (legajo) or name(nombre_empleado), based on a user input which is a numeric parameter(Orden).
I am trying to order the list by id or name in DESCENDING order (when Orden= 2 or 4), but I can´t figure out how to do it. I am using phpMyAdmin

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM empleado AS e
      INNER JOIN funcion AS f ON f.id_funcion = e.id_funcion
      INNER JOIN turno AS t ON t.id_turno = e.id_turno
      INNER JOIN convenio AS c ON c.id_convenio = e.id_convenio
ORDER BY
    (CASE
     WHEN Orden = 1 THEN legajo
     WHEN Orden = 3 THEN nombre_empleado
     WHEN Orden = 2 THEN legajo
     WHEN Orden = 4 THEN nombre_empleado
     END);
END
```

I tried:
-Adding DESC in both

```
WHEN Orden = 2 THEN legajo DESC
WHEN Orden = 4 THEN nombre_empleado DESC
```

-Making two separate CASEs

```
  CASE
     WHEN Orden = 1 THEN legajo
     WHEN Orden = 3 THEN nombre_empleado
     END ASC,
  CASE
     WHEN Orden = 2 THEN legajo
     WHEN Orden = 4 THEN nombre_empleado
     END DESC
```

-Adding ELSEIF

None works, as I get an SQL syntax error. Is there a way around it? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How should employees with different `Orden` be ordered relative to each other?

Answer (score 0):

A case expression is going to generate a single column of data, in this case a temporary column that is used for ordering. As such, it can't contain both a number and a string as mixing types in a column isn't supported. Furthermore, casting the id/int to a string would cause mysql to perform lexicographical ordering, which is probably not what you want for your id column.

Instead you could sort by ID and Name separately:

```
ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN Orden IN (2,4) THEN 0 ELSE legajo END,
     nombre_empleado
```

That will set the `id` in this temporary order by column to `0` when `Orden` is `2` or `4` so those records get sorted before any `legajo` where the `orden is` 1`or`3`. Then for all of those` 0`records, it will take a second sort of`nombre_empleado`. If you want the` orden in (2,4)`records sorted last, then you could change that`0`to a number higher than any`legajo` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would take a calculated (virtual column) for this and use that to order things out. Like;

```
SELECT *, 
@order_column := IF(order IN (2, 4), 'id', 'name') AS order_column, 
IF(@order_column = 'id', 1, 2) AS order_type_column
FROM my_table
ORDER BY order_column IF(order_type_column = 1, 'ASC', 'DESC')
```

You may need to adjust the order_type_column with some trial and error, but that is the very basic idea.